# How to get the image from a facebook photo comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

Either API or FQL, I am trying to get the photo submitted as comment in a photo post.

To make clearer here is what I am saying

- I post a photo on my page timeline.
- people now post comments on the said photo
- either text comment or attaching photo in each comment.

Now, what I am getting is the comment information only.
I want to get the information about the photo used in comment also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The **picture** (in the **comment**) could be fetched with the `attachment` parameter.

By default, you did not get the attachment field in the result, so you have to write this field explicitly. just like this -

```
me/posts?fields=comments.message,comments.id,comments.attachment
```

[Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts%3Flimit%3D1%26fields%3Dcomments.message%2Ccomments.id%2Ccomments.attachment)

Ref: [Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/)

Comment: I think that it's the correct answer but I have seen cases where this request does not give the attachment field: it is empty despite the fact that the relevant comment contains a photo

Answer (score 0):

This is the same for page comments as I just discovered:

`/{page-post-id}/comments?fields=from,message,id,attachment,created_time,comments.fields(from,message,id,attachment,created_time)`

this will return all replies (and replies to those replies) for a particular page post. if there is an image on a reply it will be under 'attachment'

result is a bit like this:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ***********
                            [id] => ***********
                        )

                    [message] => test reply with a picture
                    [id] => ***********
                    [attachment] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => photo
                            [target] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => ***********
                                    [url] => ***********
                                )

                            [url] => ***********
                            [media] => Array
                                (
                                    [image] => Array
                                        (
                                            [height] => 540
                                            [src] => ***********
                                            [width] => 720
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [created_time] => 2014-03-29T11:59:53+0000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ***********
                            [id] => ***********
                        )

                    [message] => ***********
                    [id] => ***********
                    [created_time] => 2014-03-29T11:55:09+0000
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ***********
                            [id] => ***********
                        )

                    [message] => ***********
                    [id] => ***********
                    [created_time] => 2014-03-29T11:16:45+0000
                    [comments] => Array
                        (
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [from] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => ***********
                                                    [id] => ***********
                                                )

                                            [message] => ***********
                                            [id] => ***********
                                            [created_time] => 2014-03-29T11:18:07+0000
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [from] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => ***********
                                                    [id] => ***********
                                                )

                                            [message] => ************
                                            [id] => ***********
                                            [created_time] => 2014-03-29T11:18:48+0000
                                        )
```